# red5 recorder set up on linux

Tags: linux, streaming

Does anyone know how to set up this Red5 Recorder application on Red5 1 RC2 for Linux CentOS 6.4? NB: http://www.red5-recorder.com/ NOT CREATED BY RED5 server developers

I followed set up of WEB-INF folder from this document http://fms.denniehoopingarner.com/newapp.html

I can get to the swf mysite.net:5080/red5recorder/bin-debug but it is getting error because stuck in local rtmp url and looking in red5recorder.html there doesn't seem to be anywhere to input my url for rtmp. The installer just flashes and disappears.

I don't see how even if I can edit URL, how I can get directory structure correct so it opens in red5recorder folder like the other apps in webapps folder.

I need to use the installer provided but it just, as I said before, flashes and then goes.

Comment: Just you need to get install red5 in centos or you need to configure after Installation ?

Comment: I have RED5 installed, it is a separate application not created by RED5 team that offers RED5-recorder http://www.red5-recorder.com/